# Python - passing positional arguments in class header to metaclass

Tags: python, parameter-passing, metaprogramming

Passing positional arguments in form `*(1, 2, 3)` is syntactically alowed after keyword arguments. This code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(meta, *args)

class A(metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty', *(10,)): pass
```

gives me an error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Why is positional argument intermixed with superclass list?
I think Python should be able to handle this special case because such implementation forces metaclass user to pass arguments in keyword-only manner and such interface choice is taken away from metaclass programmer.

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? Your `__new__` implementation is broken, anyway, since it returns `None` instead of a class instance

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Right I fixed example. But that still doesn't matter because of the error.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Starred expressions with a single asterisk `*` in class definitions get processed before the keyword arguments even if they appear after the keyword arguments. This leads to `*(10,)` being interpretated as base class and since `10` is not a valid base class the error message occurs.

## Explanation

The first point is that the argument list of the `__new__` method in the metaclass contains `*args`. To better understand what's going on, `*args` could be replaced with `name, bases, namespace` which are the arguments that are passed to a metaclass when it is referenced in a class definition.

So replace

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(meta, *args)
```

with

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
       return super().__new__(self, name, bases, namespace)
```

The second point is that the class definition contains a starred expression.

```
class A(metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty', *(10,)): pass
```

A *class* definition however is not a *function* definition. They may appear similar, but they follow different rules because they serve different purposes.

A *function* definition allows arbitrary positional arguments, keyword arguments and starred expressions with single asterisk `*` (variable number of positional arguments) and double asterisk `**` (variable number of keyword arguments).

A *class* definition usually includes a list of all base classes. A special case here is being able to define a metaclass with a keyword argument `metaclass=Meta` and an arbitrary number of further keyword arguments without any special meaning. The starred expression with double asterisk `**` (variable number of keyword arguments) is also supported.

> A class definition is an executable statement. The inheritance list usually gives a list of base classes (see Metaclasses for more advanced uses), so each item in the list should evaluate to a class object which allows subclassing.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

I did not find official documentation that defines the rules when using starred expressions in class definitions, but the rule for using them in calls coincidently fits with the observable behaviour.

> (...) although the *expression syntax may appear *after* explicit keyword arguments, it is processed *before* the keyword arguments  – see below). So:

```
def f(a, b):
...     print(a, b)
...
>>> f(b=1, *(2,))
2 1
>>> f(a=1, *(2,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
>>> f(1, *(2,))
1 2
```

https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#calls

Since metaclass is a keyword argument the starred expression is processed *before* metaclass, so using

```
class A(metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty', *(10,)):
    pass
```

corresponds to

```
class A(10, metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty'):
    pass
```

which can be seen in the abstract syntax tree

```
>>> import ast
>>> source = '''
... class Meta(type):
...     def __new__(meta, *args, **kwargs):
...         return super().__new__(meta, *args)
... 
... class A(metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty', *(10,)): pass
... '''
>>> 
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse(source))
"Module(body=[ClassDef(name='Meta', bases=[Name(id='type', ctx=Load())], keywords=[], body=[FunctionDef(name='__new__', args=arguments(posonlyargs=[], args=[arg(arg='meta')], vararg=arg(arg='args'), kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=arg(arg='kwargs'), defaults=[]), body=[Return(value=Call(func=Attribute(value=Call(func=Name(id='super', ctx=Load()), args=[], keywords=[]), attr='__new__', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='meta', ctx=Load()), Starred(value=Name(id='args', ctx=Load()), ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))], decorator_list=[])], decorator_list=[]), ClassDef(name='A', bases=[Starred(value=Tuple(elts=[Constant(value=10)], ctx=Load()), ctx=Load())], keywords=[keyword(arg='metaclass', value=Name(id='Meta', ctx=Load())), keyword(arg='sandwich', value=Constant(value='tasty'))], body=[Pass()], decorator_list=[])], type_ignores=[])"
```

where `bases` is defined as a starred expression containing the tuple `(10,)`

```
bases=[Starred(value=Tuple(elts=[Constant(value=10)], ctx=Load()), ctx=Load())]
```

So any non-keyword arguments in the class definition are interpreted as base classes and since `10` is not a valid base class this results in the mentioned error message.

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

## Passing arguments to metaclass

I'm not sure if it considered best practice but defining the variable positional arguments as class attribute might be meaningful way to handle things.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, classdict, *args, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            print(key + '=' + kwargs[key])
        print('*args', *classdict['args'])
        return super().__new__(self, name, bases, classdict)

class A(metaclass=Meta, sandwich='tasty'):
    args = (10,)
```

<sup>I am well aware of the age of the question, but since the first two points could possibly be of more general interest I chose to reply with an answer.</sup>